# Java: suspend frame while other frame getting information from user

Tags: java

I need to get some information from user by showing a JFrame
I need the first frame pause process until user enter data from the second frame
I thought about using wait() and notify() but I don't know how
How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to that it would be a lot easier for you is you just use a modal JDialog, which you present to the user. The inputs whatever is needed there and the JFrame that popped the dialog will carry on after the dialog's closed. wait() and notify() are used for thread synchronization btw...